# how to delete all characters after cursor in shell

Tags: shell

**I want to delete all characters after cursor in putty or shell. How can i achieve this?**

Every time I want to delete the complete line, I need to press delete key and that is something I don't want to do.

Finding a way to delete the line improve my speed and effieciency.

e.g

```
 $@ java -DSTOP.PORT=8982 -DSTOP.KEY=mysecret -jar start.jar --stop
```

@ is my cursor position so if I have to delete the line I have to keep pressing the delete key.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd>. Here are some commonly used shortcuts

**CTRL Key Bound**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> - Jump to the start of the line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> - Move back a char
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> - Terminate the command
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> - Delete from under the cursor
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> - Jump to the end of the line
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> - Move forward a char
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd> - Delete to EOL
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> - Clear the screen
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> - Search the history backwards
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> - Search the history backwards with multi occurrence
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> - Delete backward from cursor
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> - Move between EOL and current cursor position
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>@</kbd> - Show possible hostname completions
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> - Suspend/ Stop the command

**ALT Key Bound**

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd> - Move to the first line in the history
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd> - Move to the last line in the history
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>?</kbd> - Show current completion list
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>*</kbd> - Insert all possible completions
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd> - Attempt to complete filename
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> - Yank last argument to previous command
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> - Move backward
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> - Capitalize the word
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>d</kbd> - Delete word
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> - Move forward
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>l</kbd> - Make word lowercase
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>n</kbd> - Search the history forwards non-incremental
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd> - Search the history backwards non-incremental
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>r</kbd> - Recall command
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd> - Move words around
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd> - Make word uppercase
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>back-space</kbd> - Delete backward from cursor

Comment: Hit ESC key and press d , delete only single word

Comment: Which distribution are you using?

Comment: ubuntu  11 version

Comment: `CTRL k` should do it.

Comment: @jaypalsingh `CTRL k` will delete the entire line (from _start of line_ to _end of line_). They want to delete from the cursor location to the _end of line_.

Answer (score 3):

I know it's an old question, but if you like/work with vi editor, you can use:

```
$ set -o vi
```

That allows you treat the input as inside the vim editor (insert mode):

- Delete to the end of line `<ESC>D`,
- Edit entire command line inside a vim session `<ESC>v` (exiting vim executes command)
- Search in last commands `<ESC>/regexp_to_find`,
- Go to start of line `<ESC>0`,
- Insert at start of line `<ESC>I`,
- Change next word `<ESC>cw`
- Etc.

[This](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-vi-editor.htm) is one of many vim tutorials.